# The 'Traversal' attribute is not declared. In GetItem EWS request

Tags: soap, exchangewebservices, exchange-server-2010

I have EWS soap request:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"
    xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
    <soap:Header>
        <t:ExchangeImpersonation>
            <t:ConnectingSID>
                <t:PrincipalName>room1@exch2010.local</t:PrincipalName>
            </t:ConnectingSID>
        </t:ExchangeImpersonation>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <m:GetItem Traversal="Shallow">
            <m:ItemShape>
                <t:BaseShape>IdOnly</t:BaseShape>
                <t:AdditionalProperties>
                    <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:Subject"></t:FieldURI>
                    <t:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:Start"></t:FieldURI>
                    <t:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:End"></t:FieldURI>
                    <t:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:Location"></t:FieldURI>
                    <t:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:Organizer"></t:FieldURI>
                    <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:Body"></t:FieldURI>
                    <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:TextBody"></t:FieldURI>
                </t:AdditionalProperties>
            </m:ItemShape>
            <m:ItemIds>
                <t:ItemId Id="AAAUAHJvb20xQGV4Y2gyMDEwLmxvY2FsAEYAAAAAALp73pDts6BGkBAHp2xunxIHAOLiLPCbqYNEl0bu9R23VJMAAAAW2OQAAOLiLPCbqYNEl0bu9R23VJMAAAAXKY8AAA==" ChangeKey="DwAAAA=="></t:ItemId>
            </m:ItemIds>
        </m:GetItem>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

Response error is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <s:Body>
            <s:Fault>
                <faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">a:ErrorSchemaValidation</faultcode>
                <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">The request failed schema validation: The 'Traversal' attribute is not declared.</faultstring>
                <detail>
                    <e:ResponseCode xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/errors">ErrorSchemaValidation</e:ResponseCode>
                    <e:Message xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/errors">The request failed schema validation.</e:Message>
                    <t:MessageXml xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
                        <t:LineNumber>16</t:LineNumber>
                        <t:LinePosition>20</t:LinePosition>
                        <t:Violation>The 'Traversal' attribute is not declared.</t:Violation>
                    </t:MessageXml>
                </detail>
            </s:Fault>
        </s:Body>
    </s:Envelope>
```

Why would it fail?

Similar request

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<soap:Envelope
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
    xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"
    xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
    <soap:Header>
        <t:ExchangeImpersonation>
            <t:ConnectingSID>
                <t:PrincipalName>room1@exch2010.local</t:PrincipalName>
            </t:ConnectingSID>
        </t:ExchangeImpersonation>
    </soap:Header>
    <soap:Body>
        <m:FindItem Traversal="Shallow">
            <m:ItemShape>
                <t:BaseShape>IdOnly</t:BaseShape>
                <t:AdditionalProperties>
                    <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:Subject"></t:FieldURI>
                    <t:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:Start"></t:FieldURI>
                    <t:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:End"></t:FieldURI>
                    <t:FieldURI FieldURI="calendar:Location"></t:FieldURI>
                </t:AdditionalProperties>
            </m:ItemShape>
            <m:CalendarView StartDate="2016-05-30T11:08:48" EndDate="2016-12-31T11:08:48"></m:CalendarView>
            <m:ParentFolderIds>
                <t:FolderId Id="AAAUAHJvb20xQGV4Y2gyMDEwLmxvY2FsAC4AAAAAALp73pDts6BGkBAHp2xunxIBAOLiLPCbqYNEl0bu9R23VJMAAAAW2OQAAA==" ChangeKey="AgAAABYAAADi4izwm6mDRJdG7vUdt1STAAAAFtkD"></t:FolderId>
            </m:ParentFolderIds>
        </m:FindItem>
    </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

works perfectly

EDIT 1:

I have removed traversal attribute and than got error:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope
    xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Body>
        <s:Fault>
            <faultcode
                xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">a:ErrorSchemaValidation
            </faultcode>
            <faultstring xml:lang="en-US">The request failed schema validation: The 'FieldURI' attribute is invalid - The value 'item:TextBody' is invalid according to its datatype 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types:UnindexedFieldURIType' - The Enumeration constraint failed.</faultstring>
            <detail>
                <e:ResponseCode
                    xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/errors">ErrorSchemaValidation
                </e:ResponseCode>
                <e:Message
                    xmlns:e="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/errors">The request failed schema validation.
                </e:Message>
                <t:MessageXml
                    xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
                    <t:LineNumber>3</t:LineNumber>
                    <t:LinePosition>649</t:LinePosition>
                    <t:Violation>The 'FieldURI' attribute is invalid - The value 'item:TextBody' is invalid according to its datatype 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types:UnindexedFieldURIType' - The Enumeration constraint failed.</t:Violation>
                </t:MessageXml>
            </detail>
        </s:Fault>
    </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

Then I removed last Additional property

```
 <t:FieldURI FieldURI="item:TextBody"></t:FieldURI>
```

and finally got this error.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:Envelope
    xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
    <s:Header>
        <h:ServerVersionInfo MajorVersion="14" MinorVersion="3" MajorBuildNumber="123" MinorBuildNumber="3" Version="Exchange2010_SP2"
            xmlns:h="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"
            xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"/>
        </s:Header>
        <s:Body
            xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
            xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
            <m:GetItemResponse
                xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"
                xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types">
                <m:ResponseMessages>
                    <m:GetItemResponseMessage ResponseClass="Error">
                        <m:MessageText>The EWS Id is in EwsLegacyId format which is not supported by the Exchange version specified by your request. Please use the ConvertId method to convert from EwsLegacyId to EwsId format.</m:MessageText>
                        <m:ResponseCode>ErrorInvalidIdMalformedEwsLegacyIdFormat</m:ResponseCode>
                        <m:DescriptiveLinkKey>0</m:DescriptiveLinkKey>
                        <m:Items/>
                    </m:GetItemResponseMessage>
                </m:ResponseMessages>
            </m:GetItemResponse>
        </s:Body>
    </s:Envelope>
```

Please advise.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no traversal attribute in the GetItem element you can check the reference documentation https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa563775(v=exchg.150).aspx

Traversals are only valid in FindItem and FindFolder operations (its specifies what scope of Folders you are searching). GetItem is just getting a particular Item you have the Id for (The Id contains the information to locate the Item so any folder/mailbox context isn't needed). That said if you don't have rights to the particular Item and you try to use GetItem the error reported will be that the Item doesn't exist in the store (which is a little deceiving).

Edit 1

You need to start versioning all the EWS Requests you make eg in the Header

```html
  <soap:Header>
      <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2010_SP2" />
    </soap:Header>
```

You need to put the schema version https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn741586(v=exchg.150).aspx you working with (or at least put Exchange2007_SP1) . That will address the EWSId error (you won't be able to use the Id your trying to use but you should get the correct ID from the other request you got that from).